# Image inserted in PDPushButton is not visible in pdf.js(Mozilla browser)

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, pdf.js

Image inserted into PDPushButton with PDFBox is not visible when opened with Mozilla browser (pdf.js). Although it is visible in few other common renderers

```
PDPushButton pdPushButton = (PDPushButton) field;

List<PDAnnotationWidget> widgets = pdPushButton.getWidgets();
if (widgets != null && widgets.size() > 0) {
  PDAnnotationWidget annotationWidget = widgets.get(0); // just need one widget

String filePath = item.getValue();
  File imageFile = new File(filePath);

  if (imageFile.exists()) {
    PDImageXObject pdImageXObject = PDImageXObject.createFromFile(filePath, document);
    float imageScaleRatio = (float) pdImageXObject.getHeight() / (float) pdImageXObject.getWidth();

PDRectangle buttonPosition = getFieldArea(pdPushButton);
float height = buttonPosition.getHeight();
float width = height / imageScaleRatio;
float x = buttonPosition.getLowerLeftX();
float y = buttonPosition.getLowerLeftY();

PDAppearanceStream pdAppearanceStream = new PDAppearanceStream(document);
pdAppearanceStream.setResources(new PDResources());
try (PDPageContentStream pdPageContentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, pdAppearanceStream)) {
    pdPageContentStream.drawImage(pdImageXObject, x, y, width, height);
}
pdAppearanceStream.setBBox(new PDRectangle(x, y, width, height));

PDAppearanceDictionary pdAppearanceDictionary = annotationWidget.getAppearance();
if (pdAppearanceDictionary == null) {
    pdAppearanceDictionary = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
    annotationWidget.setAppearance(pdAppearanceDictionary);
}

pdAppearanceDictionary.setNormalAppearance(pdAppearanceStream);
System.out.println("Image '" + filePath + "' inserted");
field.setReadOnly(true);
  }
}
```

[Full Code example](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/form/FillImageField.java)

[PDF before insertion](https://github.com/nofelkad/pdf-sample/blob/sof/test_wo_img.pdf)

[PDF after insertion](https://github.com/nofelkad/pdf-sample/blob/sof/test_wo_img-filled.pdf)

[PDF after insertion](https://github.com/nofelkad/pdf-sample/blob/main/Sample_form_filled.pdf) (Image inserted in PDTextField instead of PDPushButton)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the PDF in question, before and after image insertion.

Comment: Added in the question

Comment: Both image pushbuttons are visible in firefox, which uses PDF.js (Windows 10)

Comment: I see nothing special in your example PDFs. In particular, the image should be visible. Thus, I would propose you file a bug with the pdf.js project... except that @Tilman's comment shows that you overgeneralized, the image does show on some pdf.js installations. Before filing the bug, therefore, you should find out what is different between the pdf.js versions that show the image and those that don't.

Comment: Correcting myself, it's not visible in the second file "Image inserted in PDTextField instead of PDPushButton". But that is likely because PDF.js clears the field area for input.

Comment: My bad , you are correct this is pdf.js 3.3.56 version issue. Works well with older version.

Comment: This particular version is shipped with Mozilla. Works well with older version and latest pdf.js (v3.4.120) published on CDN . Seems issue is only with PDF.js lib shipped with Mozilla.  Filling with them.